# Detect click on img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
 <div class="hover-bg">
   <a href="#">
    <div class="hover-text">
     <h4>Logo Design</h4>
     <small>Branding</small>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <img src="01.jpg" class="img-responsive ng-isolate-scope">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to detect clicks on an `<img/>` element. I have the following listener:

```
$('img').addEventListener 'click', ((event) ->
  console.log event
), false
```

...but the event does not fire. How can I detect the click event?

Comment: `$('img').click(function(){})`

Comment: Also I have listener on html 


$('html').on "click", (event) -> 
  console.log event



And when I click on image in console - target is always div.hover-text

Comment: @pahan40 [ https://jsfiddle.net/349zggez/ ] are you looking somethig like this .

Comment: May be something like this but ot does not work in my code. Thank you, I think I have an error in my code ( may be somewhere PreventDefault works)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `.on("click")` instead of `.click()`.

```js
 $('img').on("click", function() {
   console.log("image clicked");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-item">
  <div class="hover-bg">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="hover-text">
        <h4>Logo Design</h4>
        <small>Branding</small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
      <img src="01.jpg" class="img-responsive ng-isolate-scope">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I Understood the problem. The Problem is in positioning of hover-bg. It have absolute position and it lies over image. That's why click on it trigger event for div or div child, not image. Is It possible to detect image click when position of next element is absolute ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery click event as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        alert("The image was clicked.");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-item">
 <div class="hover-bg">
   <a href="#">
    <div class="hover-text">
     <h4>Logo Design</h4>
     <small>Branding</small>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" class="img-responsive ng-isolate-scope">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```